# Flutter Firebase caller does not have permission but rules are open

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am testing Firebase at the moment and simply trying to upload an image. For testing I have set up these rules:

**Firestore**:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    allow read, write
  }
}
```

But Flutter is complaining:

> [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.

What am I missing here? I thought my rules mean that everyone can read/write in the database.

(Like I said this is just for testing purposes, so no Auth yet)

Comment: @anirudh no, this question is with auth. I am not using auth yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if true;
  }
 }
}
```

I guess the `if true` is crucial here... didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

May be this code can help you:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```